# Django connection form connect whatever the username or the password

Tags: python, django

I'm new in Django and I try to build a connection form.
The form is created and the view to proceed it too.
However whatever the username and the password, the form redirect me as if I'm connected.

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include

urlpatterns = patterns ('pmd.views',
url(r'^connexion$', 'connexion', name="se_connecter"),
url(r'^home$', 'p_home', name="home"),)
```

**forms.py**

```
"""Formulaire de connexion"""
class ConnexionForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label="Nom d'utilisateur", max_length=30)
    password = forms.CharField(label="Mot de passe", widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

**views.py**

```
"""Vue utilisée pour se connecter"""
def connexion(request):
    connexionForm = ConnexionForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        connexionForm = ConnexionForm(request.POST)
        if connexionForm.is_valid():
            u = connexionForm.cleaned_data["username"]
            p = connexionForm.cleaned_data["password"]
            user = authenticate(username=u, password=p)
            if user is not None and user.is_valid:
                login(request, user)
                reverse_lazy(home)
    else:
        connexionForm = ConnexionForm()
    return render(request, 'pmd/connexion.html', locals())

def p_home(request):
    return render(request, 'pmd/home.html', locals())
```

**connexion.html**

```
{% extends "pmd/base.html" %}
{# Ce commentaire Django ne sera pas visible dans le code source. #}
{% block title %}Connexion{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Se connecter</h1>
    <form action="." method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ connexionForm.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Se connecter"/>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You don't have any redirect in this code at all, even when the login is successful, so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: You have to verify login return value. If it was successful, redirect to home page, if it wasn't redirect to login page again with a message or something like that to inform the user that his attempt had an error.

Comment: My bad, I misspoke between redirect and reverse_lazy

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to authenticate a user, if the user exists, you want to redirect to home, else you want to return the form back displaying the appropriate errors. you would need to make some corrections in your code.

**try this**

> forms.py

```
def clean(self):
    self.user_cache = None
    cd = self.cleaned_data
    username = cd.get('username')
    password = cd.get('password')
    if username and password:

        self.user_cache = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if self.user_cache is None:
            raise forms.ValidationError(u"Wrong Username and Password Combination.")
        elif self.user_cache is not None and self.user_cache.is_active is False:
            raise forms.ValidationError(u'Sorry, Your Account is not Activated yet.')
    return cd

def get_user(self):
    return self.user_cache
```

> views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.template import RequestContext

def connexion(request):
  connexionForm = ConnexionForm()
  if request.method == "POST":
     connexionForm = ConnexionForm(request.POST)
     if connexionForm.is_valid():
         login(request, connexionForm.get_user())
         redirect('home')
   context={'connexionForm': connexionForm}
return render(request, 'pmd/connexion.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: You've fully understood, however I have to same result with your code.

Comment: perhaps you should remove the '.' in your form action; then do some little debugging by inserting a `print(connexionForm.username)` statement under the `connexionForm.is_valid()` if statement. let me know if this works, as well as the `print` result from the console

Comment: The "." in the form was the problem indeed. Thanks a lot !